# Auto expand links to jsfiddle into embedded form

Tags: feature-request, jsfiddle, onebox

A fairly simple feature request.

Can we have links to jsfiddle posted on their own line translated into full interactive boxes of embedded jsfiddle?

For example:

```
Some content

http://jsfiddle.net/xxxxx/

Some more content
```

Should expand (behind the scenes) to

```
Some content

<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="http://jsfiddle.net/xxxxx/embedded/" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Some more content
```

It's a nice interactive feature the saves a few clicks in well formed questions.

Comment: Note, I am not talking about chat (we can discuss that too in a different thread), but about the actual main site.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141674/auto-embed-jsfiddle-into-questions

Comment: I think it would just add clutter, personally. I am not a fan of the idea.

Comment: @Ben too bad you can't close as a duplicate of another site.

Answer (score 10):

There's a bunch of discussion regarding the philosophical and technical issues with this idea here: [Auto-embed jsFiddle into questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141674/auto-embed-jsfiddle-into-questions)

You could throw together a userscript that'd do this fairly easily. In fact, [one already exists](https://stackapps.com/questions/3504/jsfiddle-preview-for-stack-overflow) - it doesn't do *quite* what you're looking for, but I'm sure you could adjust it.

Personally though, I tend to think this would just make things worse. What we really *need* is a decent code-editor integrated with PageDown - you know, one where stuff like indentation doesn't suck. Stealing the tabbed "JS | HTML | CSS" display to reduce scrolling wouldn't hurt either. We probably *don't* need a way to separately store code from the question it pertains to, which is already the problem with fiddles and which this would just encourage.

Comment: So you want [so] to *host* something like jsfiddle? That's an interesting idea. I'm just not sure if it's worth the technical effort.

Comment: A better code editor would benefit lots of folks who care nothing for debugging web pages; if we're gonna sink time into this, I think that'd be a better use of it.

Comment: We don't need no stinkin' tabs! If I have a sufficiently large enough screen, I should be able to see all the code at once and make comparisons. I don't want to have to flip between tabs. That is like looking out a picture window through mini-blinds. If there's so much code in a question that I can't see it all with minimal scrolling, there's probably *way* too much code.

Comment: You shouldn't be developing your code in a StackOverflow post. You should be copying it into StackOverflow after you made sure it works in your IDE/editor/interactive runtime.