# Inline integration of online compilers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It would be a neat feature to have an inline integration of (eventually diverse) online compilers, like [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/count) provides for example

[image: cppreference runnable code example screenshot]

I often use verifyable online compiler examples, to improve validity of my answers and just link them. Though providing this kind of format (as shown above), would be a great improvement for some code samples posted here.

**To elaborate about my actual feature request:**

I'm often [answering questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24872022/1413395) providing online compilable code samples along. So I simply put a link to the online compiler example.

Though, it might be necessary to adapt this linked example, because of question had changed, or requirements were improved. It's pretty tedious then, to have to adapt the online example, and synchronize the code sample shown in the question.

What do you think?

Comment: But we could just use online compilers like cppreference.com if we really had to compile something online.  Further, with languages that need to be compiled to a specific architecture or platform (C, C++), I'm not sure how well that'd work out.  Lastly, most code snippets/samples that I've seen are often not complete enough to compile on their own, as other pieces would need to be added in.

Comment: Just lookup the number of bugs reported on [prettify](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax-highlighting+bug). Now imagine supporting online-compilers...

Comment: @Makoto _"Further, with languages that need to be compiled to a specific architecture or platform (C, C++), I'm not sure how well that'd work out."_ Well, [ideone](http://ideone.com/), or [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) are able to work for a number of common platforms (toolchains/toolchain versions). Inlining such example, might need to proove validity, just using the correct online compiler settings and constraints. I think such could be useful for a large number of questions, just asking within constraints about current standards.

Comment: I'm not convinced that a non-trivial, non-lightweight piece needs to be integrated into the site so that we could vet questions.  I would have an expectation that the asker already has their environment configured in such a way that they have the capability of producing compilable code *before* they ask (and those that can't, there's a close reason for that).

Comment: @Makoto, I'm conflicted with that. To ask a question you *should* provide a simple example that compiles, but to answer you don't? I see users all the time telling questioners - "that doesn't even compile". Tried to tell that to an answerer the other day and was promptly informed, finishing/making it work is the last step for op. Stupid, I say. Maybe it's time to start holding those answers to a little higher standard.

Comment: @Makoto _"But we could just use online compilers like cppreference.com if we really had to compile something online."_ I'm asking about the representation format. Such that, when I'm changing the online compiler sample, the rendered sample code changes consistently. @_rene I don't see how this is related, at least not with what I'm actually intending.

Comment: I think it would be too much effort for the limited benefit. Probably 99.99% of the time I'm on overflow I'm on a machine that has at least Eclipse on it, allowing me to simple have a dummy project for that specific reason. I can simply jump over, slap the code out, copy/paste, and it's flawless every time. And if I'm not on a machine that I can write code with then I'm probably on a tab and that's surely not worth the effort.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils:  If the answer is given as an illustration, I don't really mind that; pseudocode is perfectly acceptable as an answer.  If the question is syntax dependent (why doesn't this compile?), or semantic-dependent, then I would have an expectation that it compiles or at least is *close* to compiling.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ:  I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish then.  If you want a constantly evolving piece of code on the site, then edits to the snippet by the OP can accomplish that.

Comment: @Makoto _'I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish then.'_ Simply a similar thing, like the embedded (runaable/editable/forkable) code example as provided at the cppreference.com site.

Comment: Considering that there are so many unknowable factors, and that it is incredibly easy for the question asker to create an such an example on their own and drop a link in, I vote no.

Comment: Personally, I'm in favour. See http://csharppad.com for an embeddable example for C#...

Comment: @Chris Not so much focusing on the question's samples, but the answer's.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'd be well off, with an embeddable HTML template and proposals for such ;)

Comment: Considering we don't know 1) if the post will contain executable code, 2) what language it is, and 3) if the person posting wants to use a tool we've never heard of, I just don't see the practicality of baking those assumptions in. I can go to jsFiddle, paste my code in, get a link, and paste it into my question or answer; the time it takes is trivial. Compared against the time it would take to consider the edge cases, pick winners & losers (who gets included in the baked-in list of tools), develop it, then deal with the resulting support, I just don't see it as a worthwhile use of resources.

Comment: nb: not that I totally reject the idea (especially if we could have it inline and not open in a new tab), it just doesn't seem like the most pressing need considering how easy it is to do without.

Comment: This is not the first time this has been suggested, but it is not without it's complications and has always seemed (to me) to be more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto expand links to jsfiddle into embedded form](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260600/auto-expand-links-to-jsfiddle-into-embedded-form)

Comment: @CDspace No, I'm asking broader ;) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If they don't want to do it for one kind of "fiddle site", why would they do it for a wide range of, possible ever changing, "fiddle sites"

Answer (score 7):

I also use online compilers, or "fiddles", or whatever the new jargon is for them. I almost always post my answer with one of these because it is instantly verifiable.

There are certainly numerous ones available. However, each one is backed by a group of developers and *none* are language agnostic. This means for the Stack Exchange to actually implement this it would need to make compilers for languages which are off the beaten path.

Stack Exchange would not do that, and I understand that isn't the exact request but I wanted to address that at first. My point is that it is beyond the scope of the team to create that type of feature.

In order to *integrate* third-party compilers, it would require the whitelisting of third-party elements to embed. While this would allow online compilers to be embedded, it would also introduce security concerns. Each online compiler would need be trusted not to introduce any security holes. This is a rather large concern in my opinion.

Another lesser concern is, as stated earlier, the availability of these compilers. I can think of a handful of them, but do not believe that there are enough to trust all of them for the languages which may be more obscure.

Aside from these concerns, is the actual issue being addressed a problem which needs to be solved? Linking to these online compilers is very common. In my opinion users are used to clicking through to these demos, and given that the demos create their own environment it can actually be beneficial to the user to play around with the code there. I do not believe that clicking through is a problem to most users.

tldr; Third part compilers introduce security concerns and are not readily available for enough languages. Clicking through to the demo does not detract from user experience.

Comment: _"Aside from these concerns, is the actual issue being addressed a problem which needs to be solved? "_ No, not really! Just thought of this it might be a good idea. May be really solved for particular cases using an appropriately adapted HTML template embedded in the answers markup.